# Display navigationbar when scrolling down

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uiscrollviewdelegate

On the top of the ViewController, I have a image and I hide the navigationbar, for a better visual effect.

If the user scrolls up, there is a zoom on the image. No problem so far.

If the user scrolls down, I want to display the navigation bar with animation (very light to the correct background color of the navbar)

I ve checked [here](https://www.natashatherobot.com/navigation-bar-interactions-ios8/) a good tutorial with the new possibilities with Ios8.
In fact, i need to perform the opposite of `hidesBarsOnSwipe`

So firstly, to hide the navigationbar I need to

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

And after some search, I think I will need to use `UIScrollViewDelegate`.

But I have no idea how could i implement it .

Any hint?

Comment: please try to create custom view as like navigation bar and then add animation effect which you want so thats work perfectly without any issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to do is to implement the UIScrollViewDelegate and more precisely the `scrollViewDidScroll(_:)` method ([see documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619392-scrollviewdidscroll)). This method is called each time the scroll view is scrolled.

So, in this method, you have to check that the user scrolled down and then hide the navigation bar by calling the `setNavigationBarHidden(_:animated:)` method of your current navigation controller ([see documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621885-setnavigationbarhidden))

Answer (score 0):

```
  func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let defaultOffset = view.safeAreaInsets.top
    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y + defaultOffset
    
    navigationController?.navigationBar.transform = .init(translationX: 0, y: min(0, -offset))
}

 use this function and it scrolls up the navigation bar while scrolling up and whenever you scroll down then the navigation bar appears again..
```